When I Open RSS Feed of Subdomain it shows Main Domain feed
I have created a subdomain in Hostinger single web hosting. I have installed Wordpress in it. I have imported all posts along with media in subdomain.
Problem
when I use RSS feed URL of subdomain in browser or Wordpress editor, it shows main domain posts. Even with empty subdomain site it shows main domain feed. I am unable to figure out where is the problem. Need help in this regard.
What I have Tried

I flushed cache, deleted all files, reinstalled Wordpress, issue is same

